# EMR cluster steps showing status cancelled

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I am trying to create an EMR cluster through shell script & I have added some steps (through shell script) which will be performing once EMR cluster gets created...Some of my scripts ran & showed status "**Complete**" while some showed "**Cancelled**"...When I browsed the logs of "**Cancelled**" one,it is able to print the variables what I wanted to print...but why this step is showing its status as "**Cancelled**" ??

Comment: Hi, I'm on the EMR team at Amazon. If you provide your cluster id, I could check on it for you.

Comment: Cluster id is : j-13H7VME9IFVEN

Answer (score 0):

I've seen scenarios in which the cluster terminated and then the remaining steps changed to "cancelled" status.

1. **when creating a cluster with a node type that is not supported in EMR:** the steps all were changed to cancelled before they even began.
2. **If you are using spot pricing in your cluster**, if the bid price you've set is no longer above the spot bid price threshold and your nodes get de-provisioned, it will also change the status of your nodes to cancelled.
3. **if one of the steps had enabled the setting to terminate the cluster upon failure of the step**. In that case, one of the steps fails, and the whole cluster gets killed and none of the other steps are allowed to start.

A slightly easier way to diagnose this is to create your cluster using your script and then navigate to that cluster in your EMR GUI and watch it proceed. Usually it will tell you a high level status message at the top, and if the cluster itself is getting killed, that'd be very clear in the UI.

Comment: There are total 5 steps in my cluster & 6th Step is to terminate the cluster...On all clusters,I have kept condition **Cancel And Wait**,not **Terminate**..2 steps are showing completed...while I am executing my 3rd step,In that there are 5 more child steps are added where my 1st child step is seen running & then it gets cancelled....Also,there are no errors seen in **stderr**